# How to select friends posts and my posts? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.
**Users**:
Contains user_id, username, profileimg

**Posts**:
Contains user_id (*who posted it*), posted_at *(date)*, postimg, id

**Friends**:
Contains user_a_id and user_b_id

I am struggling with pulling out all the posts made by a users friends and the user himself.
So the only input in the query is the id of the user.

I tried using joins but I am havibg trouble understanding them and their syntax.

I also tried to use other peoples queries, just trying to adapt them to my case bu I failed haha

Comment: It'll be quicker to get an answer if you take a look here first: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: we need to use nested query, writing my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to write nested query

```
select * from Posts where user_id in (select user_b_id from Friends where user_a_id = 'MY_USER_ID') OR Posts.user_id = 'MY_USER_ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because posts have only one `user_id`, the best performing method probably uses `union all`:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.user_id = :user_id
union all
select p.*
from posts p
where exists (select 1
              from friends f
              where f.user_a_id = :user_id and f.user_b_id = p.user_id
             );
```

This assumes that what you mean by "user's friends" means "`user_b_id` when you know `user_a_id`".  That is, if A and B are friends then you have both A/B and B/A in the `friends` table.

In particular, this query can take advantage of indexes on `posts(user_id)` and `friends(user_a_id, user_b_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table `posts` to a query that returns the ids of the user and friends:

```
select distinct p.*
from posts p inner join (
  select * from friends
  where ? in (user_a_id, user_b_id)
) f on p.user_id in (f.user_a_id, f.user_b_id)
```

or:

```
select distinct p.*
from posts p inner join friends f
on p.user_id in (f.user_a_id, f.user_b_id)
and ? in (f.user_a_id, f.user_b_id)
```

Replace `?` with the id of the user you search for.